# How to bind environment variable ios17

Tags: swift, swiftui, observable, ios17

With the new `@Observable` macro introduced for iOS 17, we can now use environment objects in the following way

```
@Environment(MyType.self) var myTypeObj
```

Now if `myTypeObj` has some property, call it `myProperty` which I'd like to pass as binding somewhere using `$` syntax, Swift complains that it cannot find the variable. For example,

```
Picker("My Picker", selection: $myTypeObj.myProperty) { // we get an error on this line
  ForEach(1 ... 50, id: \.self) { num in
    ...
  }
}
```

we get an error saying `Cannot find $myTypeObj in scope`. Is this a Swift bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In iOS 17 you have to use Bindable.

```
@Observable
class AppState {
    var isOn: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Environment(AppState.self) private var appState
    
    var body: some View {
        
        @Bindable var bindable = appState
        
        VStack {
            Toggle("Is On", isOn: $bindable.isOn)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .environment(AppState())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To myself and others I also think azamsharp in his video
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pe7RMWrQlZw&t=1626s) mentioned for Binding to work we have to use a separate view to bind to. But here we can see that there are another way:

1. @Environment(AppState.self) private var appState
2. @Bindable var bindable = appState
   but most **important** :this @Bindable is placed in "body View"